# hedgehog android studio project structure , no java sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, java-17

I have a project in android studio, updated to "Android Studio Hedgehog" version, but inside idea file->project structure-> project : there is no option to change jdk version, and i am receiving error that project need version java17. I wanted to change in idea env, in previous versions as i remember there was an option, tried to find the solution but there is no result. In mac os i already have java11, and cant change because i do use it for other projects. Can i somehow change version inside idea?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`